# Facing problem with opcache for the php file created in runtime with file_put_contents function

Tags: php, opcache

I have a business logic where I want to generate the PHP code in runtime and put it into the temporary file then include/require/(compile as opcache) it and delete that file. I am using opcache and want to compile/cache this newly generated code before deleting the file.

whenever I create this file manually and compile/cache it through opcache, opcache_is_script_cached command gives true. But when I create the file in runtime then opcache_is_script_cached command gives false.

```
<?php
if(!opcache_is_script_cached('/var/tmp/somefile.tmp')) {
    file_put_contents('/var/tmp/somefile.tmp', file_get_contents('var/www/html/somefolder/somefile.php'));
    opcache_compile_file('/var/tmp/somefile.tmp');
    unlink('/var/tmp/somefile.tmp');
}
```

Once this code is executed and cached into the opcache, it must not go into "if condition" and generate the code file again and again every time.